# why my wordpress wysiwyg editor keeps injecting weird html code?

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-theming, wysiwyg

I have an online store which I created with [woodmart](https://woodmart.xtemos.com/) WordPress template. every time that I use wysiwyg text editor(no matter where I am using it) I encounter this weird behavior of it, injecting the same strange html code. I have checked all plugins and also tested other themes and I believe that my theme is the culprit. Is there anyway to get rid of this issue?

[image]

Comment: Things you can do: a) use a code editor to find this code and see where it comes from, or b) switch to a different theme (eg. Twenty Twenty) and see whether this keeps happening or not: if the problem goes away after switching themes then it is indeed the Woodmart theme that's doing this, reach out to its developers for more info; if the issue persists then the "culprit" might be a plugin.

Comment: I had something similar a while ago on a rather old website. Updating Wordpress and all plugins fixed it.

Answer (score 0):

If you copy paste from a docs, pdf, website etc.. you will, most likely, copy the html with it.

Option 1:
To prevent this from happening use notepad, not even notepad++, a basic notepad will do.

Paste the content there and then copy it again and paste it inside the wysywig.

Option 2:
When using the wysiwyg editor, switch to text editor, its a tab located at the top of the wysiwyg editor.

After you pasted the content, switch back to the visual editor.

Try both options to see which option works best for you.

Comment: unfortunately even before pasting or typing or pasting anything to the editor it's already there. I delete it and save my post but again it appears

Comment: Try installing the classic editor, sometimes it also helps with cleaning the default content that is already there

Answer (score 0):

It was absurdly simple. the culprit was a chrome extension called [Highlighter](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/highlighter/fdfcjfoifbjplmificlkdfneafllkgmn) which i use occasionally but it had such a destructive effect.